# Windows Shell Automation InvokeVerb based on number instead of command string

Tags: c#, c++, powershell, winapi, explorer

Normally shell automation InvokeVerb only accepts a string command, based on the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723189(v=vs.85).aspx

However I noticed a cmd line EXE utility that accepts a number instead
http://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar

This is interesting because in Windows 10 "&Pin to taskbar" is removed from shell automation, despite being visible in the UI. ( https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1609288/pin-to-taskbar-no-longer-working-in-windows-10 )

However with this EXE passing the "number" 5386 as the command works.

I am interested to know what methods can be used to achieve this in either PowerShell/VBScript/.NET language or Win32 C/C++.

I understand this is almost certainly unsupported and likely to break any time as these numbers have changed between OS releases.

An example using the string version in PowerShell

```
$filepath = "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"
$path = Split-Path $FilePath 
$shell= New-Object -com "Shell.Application"  
$folder=$shell.Namespace($path)    
$item = $folder.Parsename((split-path $FilePath -leaf)) 
$item.InvokeVerb("&Pin to taskbar")
```

Comment: FWIW, on my Windows Server 2008R2 (Win 7) system, using the verbs `taskbarpin` and `taskbarunpin` worked, whereas "&Pin to Taskbar" and "Unpin from Taskbar" didn't work, in the call to InvokeVerb.

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant...Windows 10 RTM also works, but was disabled in an update "by design"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying shell context menu extension system actually works with numeric IDs natively; string verbs are an **optional** layer on top. However as you observe, command IDs are internal to a context menu extension and are not guaranteed to stay the same between versions (or even between invocations) - the whole point of verbs is that they allow commands to be invoked programatically irrespective of their ID.

In C/C++ you can invoke a command by its ID by casting the numeric ID as a string pointer (the rationale being that since all valid string pointers are higher than 65535, it's "safe" to pass a number as a string pointer as long as it fits into 16 bits, since the receiving API is able to correctly determine whether it is a "real string" or not).

Note that this is different from printing the number as a string, which is not correct. The [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029(v=vs.85).aspx) macro exists for exactly this purpose.

E.g., a command with ID 1234 would be invoked using `MAKEINTRESOURCE(1234)` as the verb.

Comment: are you suggesting to somehow cast a number below 65536 as a pointer to a string in Powershell? I suppose using Runtime.Marshal or some other form of .NET/COM interop that might be possible.

Comment: @user2460798 Nope, I was answering the "or Win32 C/C++" part of the question. No idea how you would do this in the other things.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem these days, in a Windows Script Host based script.

Invoking the verb with the localized string didn't work as it used to.
However you can still get the item's "Verbs" collection and then enumerate them until you get the verb you want to invoke. Then you can invoke it using it's "DoIt" method, without the need to pass the verbs name in.

In a WSH JScript it looks like this:

```
    /* workaround for 'item.InvokeVerb("&Delete")' which no longer works */

    var verbs = item.Verbs(); // item == return of folder.ParseName(..)

    for (var x = 0; x < verbs.Count; x++)
    {
        var verb = verbs.Item(x);
        if (verb.Name == "&Delete") //replace with "&Pin to taskbar"
        {                   
            try
            {
                verb.DoIt();
                WSH.Echo ("Deleted:", item.Name);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                WSH.Echo ("Error Deleting:", item.Name + "\r\n\t", e.description, e.number);
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Likely it also works somehow in PowerShell

ffr:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem-verbs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitemverb